# IBM Watson knowledge: why storage does not decrease

Tags: storage, watson-knowledge-studio

When I turn to the training model, I get an error: "Machine learning model training process failed.:This operation cannot be completed because the model size exceeds the subscription storage size 5 GB." Yesterday I deleted all snapshots, but now storage is 6Gb. Why the storage has not decreased so far?

Comment: You should open a support ticket.

Comment: thanks for the help)

Answer (score 0):

On service details it´s an alert saying that it´s necessary to wait one hour until to get the new storage status.

> Usage is updated approximately once per hour.

You can see that on rigth top corner settings icon, into Manage Service Details.

[image]

Comment: I waited more than 3 hours and it didn´t update the storage status. I opened a ticket to IBM using the link https://watson.service-now.com/wcp/?id=cs_sc_cat_item

Comment: I solved the problem open a Support Ticket to IBM. IBM Support and Dev Team recognized the problem and fixed it to my account. "The Watson Knowledge Studio dev team confirmed that the deleted models have been successfully been erased in the backend. You should now see storage: 0 GB of 5 GB."